# How new GCM handles APNS feedback?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying out new GCM feature to send notifications to iOS devices. Everything worked very smooth except the feedback message. I assume after GCM sends message through APNS, GCM also calls feedback service of APNS to get the invalid tokens. Next time when we use the same device token to GCM, it should respond with error message. I tried several times after uninstalling the app, but never received an error message from GCM. Each time it shows success message. What went wrong here?

Note: If you are not familiar with new GCM features, please do not blindly answer to this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with new GCM features, but I'm familiar with APNs. When you send a push to an iOS device you won't get any reply if the user deleted the app. Apple provides a feedback service to check deleted tokens, but they recommend querying the feedback server daily, so google might be doing so.

Comment: GCM for Android does in a different way. From package manager, GCM identifies whether app exists or not. If not, it maps the device token in server to invalid tokens and upon next request, it sends an immediate response (not a separate feedback request). I was expecting the same for GCM to iOS, but didnt work.

Comment: But GCM for iOS uses APNs internally and APNs don't return a response, you (google in this case) have to check the feedback server from time to time to check the deleted tokens. On the GCM documentation they don't mention how frequently they check the APNs

Comment: As you said, though GCM not explicitly mentioning the APNS feedback polling, developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref has a section stating "200 + error:NotRegistered - For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid."

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue? I am also not able to get the message delivered to ios using gcm. I keep on getting the error as "INVALID_REGISTRATION", however to same device token I am able to send the notification using direct APN from apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is with the environment. I am using developer certificate to test the notification. APNS may not be giving any details for developer environment. Hope it will work in production.

### Updates

---

### Support from Google gave following details.

We did some digging, it seems that is how things are being handled by APNS:

- When last sandbox app is removed from the device, device disconnects from APNS sandbox and not able to receive pushes/provide feedback anymore. Thus, APNS feedback doesn't register that the device has been uninstalled.
- If you install another push-enabled sandbox app on the device, which would force device connection to APNS again. And we checked that under this circumstance, we get notified that the device has been uninstalled and return NotRegistered to our client.

Answer (score 0):

APNS feedback service is not instantaneous. GCM does poll APNS feedback service but in my experience it was a bit delayed (not sure if it was APNS's delay or GCM's delay).

You should wait for some time and then try to use an old registration token and you should see a "Invalid Registration Token" error.